# How do I jump to the location of my last edit?

Tags: cursor-movement, command-history

I often make changes to the middle of a big file, use `gg` to jump to the top to check something, and then realize I forgot to set a mark where I was editing. Is there a built-in way to jump to the location of the last-changed line?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The `` `. `` command will bring you to your last change.

The `` ` `` goes to a mark, and `.` is a "special" mark which is automatically set to the position where the last change was made. See [`` :help `. ``](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%60.) for some more information.

There is also ``` `` ``` which will bring you back to where the cursor was before you made your last jump. See [:help ``` `` ```](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%60%60) for more information.

Another useful mark is `` `^ ``; this is the position where the cursor was the last time when insert mode was stopped. See [`` :help `^ ``](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%60%5E).

See [`:help mark-motions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#mark-motions) for some more general info about using marks (including some other "special" marks that are automatically set).

Comment: You can also use `g;` and `g,` to move between position in the change list. See `:h g;` and `:h g,`

Comment: You can also use `'` (apostrophe) instead of `\`` (backtick).

Comment: Just FYI for you guys, ideavim support `\`.` but not `g;`.  VSCode vim support both.

Comment: @pambda I'm running IdeaVim 0.65 and `g;` and `g,` both work

Comment: For vim plugin in intellij in MACOS, as far as I have observed, `` works but g; does not.

Answer (score 35):

Here's another approach that fits your given scenario, and will jump to where you were immediately prior to the `gg` (not to the last changed line).

## Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

When you press `gg`, your old cursor position is pushed onto the **jump list**. From [`:help jumplist`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#jumplist):

> Jumps are remembered in a jump list.  With the `CTRL-O` and `CTRL-I`
>   command you can go to cursor positions before older jumps, and back
>   again.  Thus you can move up and down the list.  There is a separate
>   jump list for each window. The maximum number of entries is fixed at
>   100.
>
> […]
>
> If you use a jump command, the current line number is inserted at the
>   end of the jump list.  If the same line was already in the jump list,
>   it is removed. The result is that when repeating `CTRL-O` you will get
>   back to old positions only once.

This requires that you be using Vim (not vi) with the `+jumplist` feature.
If `:echo has('jumplist')` prints `1`, then you can use this.

Answer (score 30):

To add to dnetserr's answer and Peter Rincker's comment, Vim maintains a list of changes, and has some commands associated with this.

```
:changes
```

will list the changes, showing you where they were and what they were. For example:

```
change line  col text
    2     8   17 #include <stdio.h>
    1     3    0 #include "stm32f407.auto.h"
>
```

The line with the `>` shows where in the change stack you are, kind of like the jump list (`:jumps`) or tag stack (`:tags`). Also like the jump list and tag stack, you can traverse this list.

In normal mode, the motions are `g;` to go to a previous change location, and `g,` to go to the next one. You can also type the number of the change prior to `g;` or `g,` to go to that change from the list. Above, `2g;` would take me to where the change involving stdio.h occurred.

When in the middle of the stack, the numbers from `:changes` updates to show the relative distances. For example:

```
change line  col text
    1     8   17 #include <stdio.h>
>   0     3    0 #include "stm32f407.auto.h"
    1    10    4 other
```

This shows that I can go back one (`1g;` or just `g;`) or forward one (`1g,` or just `g,`).

This is great if the change you want to get to actually occurred a few modifications ago

The disadvantage of this is that it doesn't appear to act like a normal motion. For example, you cannot do `dg;` to delete from the cursor to the previous change location, whereas `d'.` and `d'^` do work as motions.

Answer (score 24):

`g;` will go to the previously edited line.

Comment: You can also use g, (comma) to go to a newer editing position.

Answer (score 13):

Saving a character on the accepted answer:

```
gi
```

Will take the cursor to the **exact** point last edited and put you in insert mode, ready to continue typing. (It's also quicker to type!)

Answer (score 6):

Since the undo command in Vi will act as a re-do when the last command was undo, I have used `uu` as a means to go back to where I last edited.

If you're running Vim with `nocompatible` set (as most people do), you want to use `u` followed by `CTRL+R` to undo & redo. Otherwise `uu` will work as in Vi.

Comment: It will if `:set nocompatible` is not used.

Comment: My `vim` (with `nocompatible`) does two undos with `uu`, but I use `u` and `CTRL+r` for the same effect.

Comment: This answer has the advantage that it works with vi as well, in case you have no vim on Aix/HPUX/Solaris/other Unix variants.