# How do I get back to the previous line after moving?

Tags: cursor-movement

I am new to Vim. My code file has 300 lines. Suppose currently the cursor is on line 254, and I used `gg` command the cursor turn to line 1. I want to go back to line 254 but I forget that line number. Is there a command the can do this?

Comment: [Strongly related question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2001/1841) if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use ``` `` ``` to jump back to the exact position you were in before you searched/jumped, or `''` to jump back to the start of the line you were on before you searched/jumped.

You can also use <kbd>CTRL+O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+I</kbd> for jumping back and forward.

See also:

- [In vim, how do I go back to where I was before a search?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53911/123527)
- [Move cursor to its last position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5052079/123527)

Comment: See also `:help ''`, `:help 03.10`, `:help jump-motions` and `:help motion.txt`.

Comment: One really powerful thing about Ctrl+O and Ctrl+I is that it will even jump between files!