# After closing a file, how do I remember/return to the previous line?

Tags: vimrc

I'm not talking about [the previous line I was on while still editing a file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/how-do-i-get-back-to-the-previous-line-after-moving) but *after* I close a file and then enter vim again, I want to go to that line. How do I enable this?

Steps to 'reproduce':

```
vim filename.txt
:234
:q
vim filename.txt
## I want to be on line 234 now, not line 1.
```

Comment: For that you need ~/.viminfo file. Please see :help viminfo. This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012391/how-and-where-is-my-viminfo-option-set#32943292

Comment: yeah, I figured I'd need a viminfo, I've done it in some places, was wondering what the canonical way was to do so. Looks like this comment on that question is really informative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036077/659298

Comment: One way, maybe: In `/etc/vim/vimrc` seach for `Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position` and uncomment the relevant code lines. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/244885/200605).  (Also, of course, `vim +234 filename.txt`)

Comment: Will flesh out later, but use the 0 mark.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your .vimrc file:

```
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
```